# Give recursive definition of sequence $a_n = 2^n, n=2,3, 4... where $ $a_1 = 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

Give recursive definition of sequence $a_n = 2^n, n = 2, 3, 4... where $ $a_1 = 2$

I'm just not sure how to approach these problems.

Then it asks to give a def for:

$a_n = n^2-3n, n = 0, 1, 2...$

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The first one is easy: $a_{n+1}=2a_n$.  For the next one, can you similarly solve for $a_{n+1}$ in terms of the previous terms?

Comment: So is that the definition (the answer then). Could you just briefly explain how to get there? I'm new to these. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first one, write the term $a_{n+1}$ and compare it to $a_n$:
$$a_{n+1}=2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n=2a_n$$

For the second one, repeat the process:
$$\begin{align}a_{n+1}&=(n+1)^2-3(n+1)\\
&=n^2+2n+1-3n-3\\
&=n^2-3n+2n-2\\
&=a_n+2(n-1)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Okay, great! Thanks for showing how to do it so I can figure out future problems. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are lots of answers to these questions.  IMO those given by Terra Hyde are probably what your instructor is expecting, but you could also say:

for the first one,
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+2^n$$
and for the second
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}-n^2+7n-6$$
among many, many other possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense that there would be multiple answers for some of these. Thanks for letting me know, appreciate the help!

Comment: I had sort of a follow up question for anyone here, in another problem, I'm asked to give a recursive def of the set of positive integers that are a multiple of 4. So is this sort of the same thing, just working backwards a bit?

Comment: Recursive definition of a **set** is a bit different.  Suggest you post that as a separate question.